# Maximum Rectangle with all same number

Tags: dynamic-programming

> Given a array n X m. You need to find the largest rectangle which contains all same number in it.
>   Example:
>   `1 2 2 5`
>   `1 2 2 4`
>   `2 2 2 3`
>   here the answer should be 6.

I can solve this if the question ask about largest square. Here is my approach -

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
    if(!i && !j) dp[i][j] = 1; 
    else if(a[i][j] == a[i-1][j-1] && 
       a[i][j] == a[i-1][j] &&
       a[i][j] == a[i][j-1])
           dp[i][j] = min({dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j]}) + 1;
    else dp[i][j] = 1;
}
```

Then the answer should be the maximum number in the dp table. How can I modify this to get the largest rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a 3d array to store length and breadth of rect ie `dp[INT_MAX][INT_MAX][2]`.
By replacing-

```
else if(a[i][j] == a[i-1][j-1] && 
   a[i][j] == a[i-1][j] &&
   a[i][j] == a[i][j-1])
       dp[i][j] = min({dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j]}) + 1;
```

With-

```
else if(a[i][j] == a[i-1][j-1] && 
   a[i][j] == a[i-1][j] &&
   a[i][j] == a[i][j-1])
{     
        //for length along j
      dp[i][j][0]=min(dp[i][j][0]+1,dp[i-1][j-1][0]+1,dp[i][j][0]);

       //for length of rectangle along i
      dp[i][j][1]=min(dp[i][j][1],dp[i-1][j-1][1]+1,dp[i][j][1]);
}
```

Rest are trivial cases where the rectangle is single lined and can be solved using simple if-else.